# Problemas com "Back Button" no navegador

Tags: iframe, navegador-de-internet

Galera, tudo bem?

Preciso de uma enorme ajuda, na verdade eu nem sei se isso é possível.
O lance é o seguinte, eu criei um página que tem um iframe, até ai tudo bem, o problema é quando eu clico no botão voltar do navegador,  em vez de ele retornar a página anterior, ele permanece na mesma página.
Quando eu insiro o ponteiro do mouse sobre o botão voltar e mantenho pressionado, ele exibe o endereço do iframe (url).
Sendo bem objetivo, o que eu preciso é, quando o usuário acessar a página com iframe e clicar em voltar, ele respeite e retorne a página anterior, segue abaixo um cenário.

```html
<div class="iframe desktop-iframe"><iframe align="top" allowtransparency="true" application="true" frameborder="0" height="360px" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="content" scrolling="no" src="url-do-iframe-que-e-exibida" vspace="0" width="100%"></iframe></div>

<div "conteudo">
<p> texto </p>
</div>
```

Tipo, eu tenho meu index.html que possui um link para a página com iframe, ao chegar nessa página com iframe e clicar no botão voltar, deveria retornar para a index.html mas ele permanece na mesma página :(

Conseguem me ajudar com isso?

Obrigado galera

Comment: Acontece que quando vc abre o navegador e acessa seu index.html não tem nada no seu  histórico pra voltar, o navegador não interage nos iframes do mesmo modo que interage nas página "normais".

Comment: Vinicius, mas são 2 páginas diferentes, o iframe está em uma subhome, tipo eu tenho o index.html e quando eu clico em um link ele aponta para uma página diferente do próprio index.html, ou seja, quando eu acessar a página do iframe, ele deveria retornar para o index.html

Comment: Realmente deveria voltar. Faça um teste: remova o iframe da página e veja se volta pro index.html.

Comment: Quando você diz botão voltar, está se referindo ao botão voltar do navegador, ou existe de fato um botão voltar dentro do iframe?

Comment: Seria o back button ( Botão voltar com a setinha esquerda) do chrome mesmo. Se eu remover o iframe, ele volta numa boa.